# Eloquent hasMany does not work with point symbol

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have two tables, one products and the other warehouses. It is a 1 to N relationship since an item can have stock in several warehouses.
I have it related in the model with hasMany indicating the primary key and it works perfect for me, the problem is that some of the article codes have points, an example code would be this "1.51.00.1003356". When making the query it does not return the stock of that product, it only happens with those that have points, the others work well. How can i fix this?

This is my model Product

```
class Product extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'products';
    protected $primaryKey = 'sku';
    protected $casts = ['sku' => 'string',];


    public function stock()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Product\Warehouse','id_product');
    }
}
```

This is my model Warehouse

```
class Warehouse extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'Warehouses';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id_product';
    protected $casts = ['id_product' => 'string',];
}
```

My Eloquent query is as follows:

```
$products = Product::with('stock')
->where('products.sku','=','1.51.00.1003356')
->first();
```

Comment: can you just create another primary key "id" and have sku as another string field.

Comment: I have considered this possibility, but before doing it like this, I wanted to know if it is possible to do it using sku code